# Disable WooCommerce email notification for specific payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to disable email for payment method a "cod".  processing order.

How can I create a code for this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check for the procesing order, but thats the code for on hold orders:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_on_hold_order', 'customer_on_hold_order_for_specified_payment', 10, 2 );

function customer_on_hold_order_for_specified_payment( $recipient, $order ) {
 
   if ( 'wirecard_ee_creditcard' == $order->get_payment_method() ) {
       $recipient = '';
   }
   return $recipient;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove email notification for pending and on hold orders.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'unhook_new_order_processing_emails' );
function unhook_new_order_processing_emails( $email_class ) {
   // Processing order emails
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
}
```

for more details check email hooks
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/unhookremove-woocommerce-emails/